# Python/MEL code equivalent of Display>Border Edges in Maya

Tags: python, maya, mel

I want to toggle in my script the border edges display but I can't seem to find it in the documentation nor in mel echo commands. How do you call this?

Comment: wow, this tags are pretty unpopular here. Anyway, here's the answer: setPolygonDisplaySettings("borderEdge");

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to UVborders or Mesh edges?

You can use the following code to toggle mesh Display edges.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds 

poly_obj = cmds.ls(selection=True) #select a poly in Maya


bordersState = cmds.getAttr('{}.displayBorders'.format(poly_obj[0]))

if bordersState:
    cmds.setAttr('{}.displayBorders'.format(poly_obj[0]), 0)
else:
    cmds.setAttr('{}.displayBorders'.format(poly_obj[0]), 1)
```